# How to share/pass a variable among multiple thread groups within jmeter and without using beanshell assertion

Tags: variables, jmeter

I have declared 1 user defined variable (A=wait) in a test plan and I have 2 thread groups in the test plan. When 1st thread group completes it's execution then I have changed the value to "go" (A=go) using beanshell post processor. Now, in second thread group I want that (A) should be pick the updated value (means "go" not "wait") but I am not able to pick the updated value in 2nd thread group. I am not using any regular expression extractor, just using and updating user defined variable.

I tried beanshell pre and post processor. First I created 1 bean shell sampler in which I changed the value(vars.put("A1","go");) then I created 1 beanshell postprocessor (${__setProperty(A,${A1})}) in first thread group and then in 2nd thread group I added BeanShell preprocessor to get the value (${__property(A)})

I also used beanshell assertion to pass the variable to next thread group but next thread group didn't catched the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use scripting - take a look at [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)

There is an [example test plan](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) showing how variables could be shared.

Going forward be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for scripting and in Groovy you should avoid inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

So:

1. In first thread group:

   ```
   props.put('A', 'go')
   ```
2. In second thread group:

   ```
   go = props.get('A')
   ```

   or if you prefer a function:

   ```
   ${__P(A,)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]